# How to solve stopiteration error? i got Traceback (most recent call last) error

Tags: python

This is the code that i wrote:

```
img_files = next(os.walk('MyDrive/FYP/Fig_Dataset'))[2]
msk_files = next(os.walk('MyDrive/FYP/Ground_Truth'))[2]

img_files.sort(2)
msk_files.sort(2)

print(len(img_files))
print(len(msk_files))

X = [2]
Y = [2]

for img_fl in tqdm(img_files):    
if(img_fl.split('.')[-1]=='jpg'):
    img = cv2.imread('MyDrive//FYP/Fig_Dataset/{}'.format(img_fl))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    resized_img = cv2.resize(img,(256, 192), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    X.append(resized_img)
    
msk = cv2.imread('MyDrive//FYP/Ground_Truth/{}'.format(img_fl.split('.')[0]+'_segmentation.png'),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    resized_msk = cv2.resize(msk,(256, 192), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    Y.append(resized_msk)
```

And this is the error that i got

```
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-40a26ba7758c> in <module>()
----> 1 img_files = next(os.walk('FYP/Fig_Dataset'))[2]
```

i dont know how to solve this. Help me

Comment: `[2]` is apparently out of range for that iterator. Have you tried `print(list(os.walk('MyDrive/FYP/Fig_Dataset')))` to confirm how many entries exist?

Comment: Here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65013199/stopiteration-error-while-trying-to-build-data-input-for-a-model

Comment: `os.walk` returned an iterator, but there wasn't anything to iterate. The `next` had nothing to emit, so rasied StopIteration. This is the normal thing when a directory doesn't exist or is empty. If that's a normal case, then catch the exception and stop the other work. Otherwise its a legitimate indication of a bug.

Answer (score 0):

`os.walk` returns a generator which is a type of iterator. Iterators emit values from a sequence and then raise `StopIteration` when done. `next` tries to get the next value from an iterator. The iterator, following the rules just noted, will either return the next value or raise `StopIteration`.

Since you saw `StopIteration` on the first `next` call, it means that `os.walk` didn't find the path at all. There was nothing to iterate, so `StopIteration` was raised immediately. You could catch this exception as a way of knowing that the directory itself was invalid.

```
try:
    fig_path = 'MyDrive/FYP/Fig_Dataset'
    img_files = next(os.walk('MyDrive/FYP/Fig_Dataset'))[2]
    msk_files = next(os.walk('MyDrive/FYP/Ground_Truth'))[2]
except StopIteration:
    print("Directory not found")
    exit(2)
```

The remaining question is why these paths aren't correct. You could do `print(os.getcwd())` to see your current path.